# I'm working on a game and want to reference some other games and movies. How much trouble could I get in with the examples below?

Tags: copyright

I'm wondering what trouble a game developer could get into with making references to other things that served to inspire the dev. Suppose the dev plans to sell the game; would such references possibly cause issues later down the line

---

I refer tpo references such as, for example:

- drinking bird (*Alien* movies)
- Glasses with "A. Wesker" written on the side (Resident Evil)
- A brochure that advertises The Overlook (*The Shining*)
- Newspaper talking about a shark killing "Martha Vineyard", aged 75 (*Jaws*)
- One of the lockers has the name "S. Henriksson" (Cry of Fear)
- Book titled something like "The favourite fellow" by Charles L. Ray (Chucky)

Answer (score 4):

In general this kind of brief literary reference is not unlawful, and such things occur in both novels and commercial games with some frequency. Making such a reference a major part of the plot, such as by using a name from a previous work as a major character, particularly if other aspects of that character are also used, is far more likely to cause a problem.

In the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states) this would be a matter of ***fair use***. In general, when only a very small part of the source work is used, such a a single name; where the use is "transformative", that is used for a rather different purpose than in the source work; where the use does not harm the market for the original work; and where the use does not serve as a replacement for the original, it is likely to be held to be fair use. But fair use decisions are always fact-dependent, and are made case-by-case, so it is hard to be absolutely sure of one in advance. But the kind of literary reference described in the question is very unlikely to be held to be copyright infringement.